# Как перенести данные с cs-cart в woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, импорт

С cs-cart могу экспортировать только [CSV](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HHa35G2x911-RBokMrH6vPfGTJDUEreKdR69VqAzSsc/pubhtml)

но как этот csv правильно импортировать в woocommerce

вот пример карточки [image: товара]

может есть и другие способы это сделать?